# foreach loop doesnt seem to be looping correctly

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Using jquery, I've created this foreach loop for ajax to be displayed into html/bootstrap:

```
$(document).ready(() => {



         let $newList = $(".listDeals");

          $.getJSON('data/search.json', (deal) => {

              console.log(deal)
              $.each(deal, (i) => {

            $newList.append(`<li><a role=button data-toggle=modal data-target=#myModal href=#>${deal[i].Name} <i class="fa fa-gamepad fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            <div class="modal fade" id=myModal>
  <div class=modal-dialog>
    <div class=modal-content>


      <div class=modal-header>
        <h4 class="modal-title">${deal[i].Name}</h4>
        <button type=button class=close data-dismiss=modal>&times;</button>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        ${deal[i].deals}
      </div>

      <div class=modal-footer>
        <button type=button class=btn btn-secondary data-dismiss=modal>Close</button>
      </div>

      </div>
      </div>
      </div>`);


              })
               })
```

The problem I'm having with this is mainly on the lines:

- `<h4 class="modal-title">${deal[i].Name}</h4>`
  and
- `<div class="modal-body">${deal[i].deals}</div>`

For some reason, they are stuck on the first item coming from the ajax/JSON file. I'm unsure how to loop the other bits. The rest of the code, however, is fine.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is on the ID of your modal. all the generated modals all have the same ID which is myModal. That is why all calls for that modal always calls the first modal. You need to make the ID dynamic. see code below:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {



         let $newList = $(".listDeals");
         var x = 0;
          $.getJSON('data/search.json', (deal) => {

              console.log(deal)
              $.each(deal, (i) => {
                x++;
            $newList.append(`<li><a role=button data-toggle=modal data-target=#myModal`+x+` href=#>${deal[i].Name} <i class="fa fa-gamepad fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal`+x+`">
  <div class=modal-dialog>
    <div class=modal-content>


      <div class=modal-header>
        <h4 class="modal-title">${deal[i].Name}</h4>
        <button type=button class=close data-dismiss=modal>&times;</button>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        ${deal[i].deals}
      </div>

      <div class=modal-footer>
        <button type=button class=btn btn-secondary data-dismiss=modal>Close</button>
      </div>

      </div>
      </div>
      </div>`);


              })
               })
```